# How use select statement with count(*)

Tags: sql-server

I have some tables following

```
Room(CodeR, NameR)

Title(CodeT,NameT)

Member(ID,Name, Salary, Sex, CodeR, CodeT)
```

I want write the sql to select Roooms that member less than 5 and print all member of this room.

Please help me solve this problem

pls help me remove this topic. i can not ask any question.

Comment: Your post needs to include what you have tried so far.

Comment: Sorry I don't have data. Just have above description. Can you remove this question for me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select R.CodeR, NameR, m.Id, m.Name FROM
Room R INNER JOIN Member m on
R.CodeR = m.CodeR
WHERE R.CodeR in 
(SELECT iM.CodeR FROM Member iM GROUP BY iM.CodeR HAVING COUNT(*) <5)
```

First of all pull all the rooms where no of members are less than 5

```
SELECT iM.CodeR FROM Member iM GROUP BY iM.CodeR HAVING COUNT(*) <5
```

Then pull out room and member information as required using above result.

```
select R.CodeR, NameR, m.Id, m.Name FROM
Room R INNER JOIN Member m on
R.CodeR = m.CodeR
WHERE R.CodeR in (X, Y, Z) //X, Y, Z will be replaced by subquery
```

Comment: A little bit of context or explanation would improve this answer.

Comment: @Thomas: thanks for suggestion..which made me review my code and make a correction :)

Comment: And that earns you a +1